# VBA - INNER Join on Update SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

My application currently has the following SQL code to mark of surveys if an email has been sent and then marks off the job with a date field.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "UPDATE J SET J.PrewarnFranDate = DATE() FROM (dbo_Franchises AS F INNER JOIN dbo_Customers AS C ON F.FranchiseNo=C.FranchiseNo) INNER JOIN dbo_Jobs AS J ON C.CustomerId=J.CustomerId WHERE (F.SortOrder<98) AND (C.NeverSurveyCust=0) AND (J.NotProceedingDate IS NULL) AND (J.HandoverDate < " & Date() - 28 & ") AND (J.SendFlag = 0) AND (J.SurveyId IS NULL);"
```

Currently when the code is run it produces the following error and i can't for the life of me figure out why as the syntax looks correct.

[image: screenshot of syntax error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice guys but my issue ended up being really silly. The original issue is that access handles update with multiple inner joins in a funny way. i had to reformat the query to read as per below.

```
"UPDATE (dbo_jobs AS J Inner Join DBO_Customers as C on C.customerid = j.customerid) INNER JOIN dbo_franchises as F on F.FranchiseNO = C.franchiseno set j.prewarnfrandate =# " & Date & "# where F.sortorder < 98 and c.neversurveycust = 0  and j.notproceedingdate is null and J.handoverdate < #" & Date - 28 & "# and j.sendflag = 0 and j.surveyid is null;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one first.

```
UPDATE J
SET PrewarnFranDate = DATE()
FROM dbo_Franchises AS F
INNER JOIN dbo_Customers AS C
  ON F.FranchiseNo = C.FranchiseNo
INNER JOIN dbo_Jobs AS J
  ON C.CustomerId = J.CustomerId
WHERE F.SortOrder < 98
AND C.NeverSurveyCust = 0
AND J.NotProceedingDate IS NULL
AND J.HandoverDate < " & Date() - 28 & "
AND J.SendFlag = 0
AND J.SurveyId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you put the second date() function outside of the query string, you have to do the same with the first date() function.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "UPDATE J SET J.PrewarnFranDate =#" & DATE() & "# FROM...
```

You may need to enclose your second date function in `#` signs as well.

```
"AND (J.HandoverDate < #" & Date() - 28 & "#) AND...
```

Comment: Yeah i had a look at that as well sadly it was not the case, putting the date format outside of the sql query did not work, receiving the same missing operator error. I feel as though the issue may be with the joining rather than the query itself. Especially considering access is a bit funny with multiple inner joins.

Comment: CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "UPDATE J SET PrewarnFranDate = '#" & Date & "#' FROM (dbo_Franchises F INNER JOIN dbo_Customers C ON F.FranchiseNo=C.FranchiseNo) INNER JOIN dbo_Jobs J ON C.CustomerId=J.CustomerId WHERE (F.SortOrder<98) AND (C.NeverSurveyCust=0) AND (J.NotProceedingDate IS NULL) AND (J.HandoverDate < " & Date - 28 & ") AND (J.SendFlag = 0) AND (J.SurveyId IS NULL);", , adExecuteNoRecords + adCmdText